# Backslashes in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, quoting

Why does the string for the -split parameter require two backslashes while the string for the -join parameter requires only one backslash? The backtick is the escape character in Powershell. What does a backslash preceding a character do for you?

```
$path = 'C:\folder\test\unit1\testing\results\report.txt'

$path -split '\\' -notlike '*test*' -join '\'
```

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/06/17/fun-with-path-names.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-split` splits on a regex by default.  So it is the regex that requires escaping a backslash. You can tell PowerShell not to use a regex like so:

```
$path -split '\',-1,'SimpleMatch'
```

`-join` is just taking whatever characters you supply to use as the delimiter to stick between the strings being joined.

Comment: To anyone wondering, `-split` can take up to 3 parameters: `<delimiter>`, `<max-substrings>`, `<options>`, so in Powershell <7.0, `-split '\', -1, 'SimpleMatch'` means to split on `\\`, return _all_ matches (max-substrings of 0 or lower returns all in PS <7.0), and use SimpleMatch instead of the default RegexMatch. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 3):

-split is accepting a regular expression where backslash is special character, so it need to be escaped